# Small issue on downvote tooltip (click again to undo?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, status-bydesign, down-votes, tooltips

Just a small issue on the downvote tooltip:

[image: downvote sample]

I don't think `click again to undo` is true, because a downvote needs an edit to be cancelled.

---

## Edit

Thanks @juergend about the grace period. But @matt is right, this tooltip is not updated after the grace period:

[image]

If I click on the downvote again, I can see 2 opposites tooltips.

[image]

Comment: Well you can undo or voteup within a short period of time without Editing the post.

Comment: ... so in that case, maybe the tooltip could be updated once the grace period has expired?

Comment: This drives me bonkers

Comment: May I ask have this is status completed and status bydesign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the issue regarding the additional "click again for undo" text on a selected up- or down-vote is resolved in build rev 2013.7.3.803.

The second part regarding validation of vote actions won't be addressed as it would require push notifications about each question and answer on the page to be sent out to everyone currently viewing it.

Comment: ... which introduced this bug:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187170/upvote-and-downvote-tooltip-always-says-answer#187174

Comment: I don't need it to refresh instantly, but it actually doesn't even refresh after page refresh.  When the page is initially loaded it shouldn't show "click to undo" unless you can actually click to undo.

Answer (score 5):

There is a 5 minute *grace period* in that you can undo your vote. So this tooltip is correct.

Imagine you use a phone and click the *downvote* button instead of the *favour* button. You can undo that. After 5 minutes your vote is *locked* until the post is edited.

### Edit

Many things in the GUI are not updated. You still have vote buttons on deleted questions for instance. When the vote is locked the best thing would be to visually deactivate the vote buttons until the post is edited.

Remember you are in a browser and not in a program!

Comment: +1 for perfect detailed information ( 5 minutes for my words short period )

Comment: To answer your last sentense, this is not a P1 bug I assume, this is just to pointing it out.