# Upvote and downvote tooltip always says "answer"

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, tooltips

The upvote/downvote tooltip here on Meta was changed to simply "this answer is useful" or "this answer is not useful". Nice and dandy. Only problem is, that it's showing that tooltip on the upvote/downvote arrows for **question** as well. Taking [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180315/152859) as example to demonstrate:

> [image]

I know the irony and maybe it was better to edit that other report adding yet another part but it already got 5 tags so no place for additional [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) once it would be fixed. :)

Comment: Doesn't happen on this particular meta post, but it does on the linked one for some reason.

Comment: It seems to only happen on questions with an answer? Let me try that. Yep, that's the case. Added an answer and hey presto!

Comment: @Bart yep, good catch!

Comment: looking into it

Comment: @m0sa this comment is useful. ;)

Comment: Ooh, some good detective work going on here.

Comment: I'm seeing this on SO and SU as well, not just Meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed, should work correctly everywhere now.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that the error only applies to questions that have at least one answer.

For your question, for example, I first saw:

[image: Correct tooltip]

but as soon as there were answers (including this one), we see:

[image: Incorrect tooltip]

Comment: That's weird. When I see this question, I see exactly what the OP stated.. O.o

Comment: You [stole the fame](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187170/upvote-and-downvote-tooltip-always-says-answer/187174?noredirect=1#comment575028_187170) from poor Bart! ;)

Comment: @JAnderton that ironically seems to happen because Martijn posted this answer. :)

Comment: I think this is not an answer

Comment: Hey, he stole it first! I was making screenshots! :-D

Comment: Pff, screenshots are so last year.

Comment: No waffles for you! And saving the acceptance to Mr. m0sa once he fix what he broke. :-)

Comment: But wait, how did you test this by leaving an answer if this is they answer you were leaving when you were testing it... Am I in The Matrix or something?

Comment: @Azik it's a dev guide to help him hunt the bug down and slay it.

Comment: @JonW: You unlock this door with the key of imagination. Beyond it is another dimension - a dimension of sound, a dimension of sight, a dimension of mind. You're moving into a land of both shadow and substance, of things and ideas. You've just crossed over into the Twilight Zone.

Comment: @Martijn did I hear shadow??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Hey, we are doing all the diagnostic work for him! :-P